# JQuery syntax for multiple operations

Tags: jquery, syntax, filter

I have a list if `<span>` elements, which I need to filter and apply multiple operations (text replacement and add a class conditionally). I have the following working code:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
     return $(this).text().toLowerCase()==phrase;
}).text(translation);

$('span').filter(function() { 
     return $(this).hasClass('translatable') && $(this).text().toLowerCase()==phrase;
}).addClass(translated);
```

This works, but is clearly going through all the `<span>`s twice. Is it possible to combine them into one iteration, something on the lines of:

```
$('span').filter(function() { 
     return $(this).text().toLowerCase()==phrase;
}).function() {
     $(this).text(translation);
     if($(this).hasClass('translatable'))
         this.addClass("translated")
}
```

Comment: Just chain the methods: `.text(translation).addClass(translated);`

Comment: @billyonecan yes I think so at first, but regarding the code in more detail, the filter is over the text that can be replaced between both methods...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie if that were the case, the `translated` class would never get added (as the text would have been replaced after the preceding filter function). I still think it's just a case of method chaining

Comment: @billyonecan I think you are right but if this the case, thus the code indicated by the OP is not correct since the text has changed between the 2 selections... Amarsh : can you confirm the logic expected there : you have to add the class when the text has been replaced as indicated by billyonecan or your logic is the correct one (the class is being added after the translation)?

Comment: oh i could have been more precise ... i want to do the second operation conditionally ... I am editing my question to reflect this

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie I agree, it's not completely clear what the OP is trying to achieve here

Comment: @Amarsh : I have added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/DWTF4/) in order to show the difference between your code ("Translate - 1") and the method proposed by billyonecan ("Translate - 2"). Can you validate what is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `phrase` test is the same for both of your filters I'd probably approach it like this:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
     return $(this).text().toLowerCase()==phrase;
})
.text(translation)
.filter('.translatable')
.addClass('translated');
```

That is, first find the spans containing that phrase and set their text, then filter that set to get the subset that has the `translatable` class and add the `'translated'` class just to those.

Comment: Thanks ... this one appears the most concise ... although I wonder why the other guys thing that each() is faster that filter() ... I presume filter() would be faster (if there is some indexing against class name in the DOM tree) or the same as for each(). Thanks a lot to all contributers.

Comment: The first `filter()` loops over every span in the document. Then `.text()` loops over every span that passed the filter. Then the second `.filter()` loops over every span that passed the previous filter. Then `.addClass()` loops over that subset. If you use `.each()` as per the other answer then each span in the document is processed exactly once, so it would make sense that it would be faster. In my projects I'd start with code similar to my answer because it is compact and easy to follow; if there was a performance problem I'd go to the `.each()` method, or even a plain `for` loop.

Comment: aaah I get it ... actually mine is more of a "sparse-matrix" type situation ... of over 500 spans, only 5 or so will qualify the first filter (I naively assumed that the browser indexes DOM elements by classNames, hence filter() will be O(1) while each will be O(n)), hence the subsets will be even smaller ... whereas each() will iterate all over. Thanks everyone for help again.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with jQuery's each method

```
$('span').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().toLowerCase()==phrase){
        $this.text(translate);
        if ( $this.hasClass('translatable') ) {
            $this.addClass("translated");
        }
    }    
});
```

Or you could chain methods

```
$('span').filter(function(){ return $(this).text().toLowerCase()==phrase; })
         .text(translate)
         .filter(function(){ return $(this).hasClass('translatable'); })
         .addClass("translated");
```

I personally prefer the first approach. Although it isn't as pretty as the first, it is truly one iteration unlike the second approach where there are four separate iterations. With the correct optimizations (thanks Samuel Caillerie) it should be slightly faster.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There's no need to use `.each()`, the `.filter()` method is fine

Comment: @billyonecan it answers the question "Is it possible to combine them into one iteration".

Comment: @GregGuida please note that if you want to proceed with your method, you should cache `$(this)` or else the performance would be bad... The solution proposed by billyonecan avoid this issue!

Comment: lemme try replacing $('span'). with $('span').filter(function() {return $(this).text().toLowerCase()==phrase;}) ... ie, create the filtered array and then operate on each element

Comment: +1 - Now that I understand what the OP is trying to achieve. I haven't tested, but I imagine the `each` method would be faster than performing two `filter()`'s